# why does -CHO hold higher priority over -CH2OH according to CIP rule

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

i am unable to find proper resources to learn CIP rule at a high school level withut delving deeper into terms i cant understand and hence the basic confusion.if i am correct one has to first compare the atomic wieght of groups down the chain until a tie is broken

so in $\ce{-CHO}$ and $\ce{-CH2OH}$ , first we see that both compound have $\ce{C}$ attached
then $\ce{-CHO}$ has $\ce{=O}$ while $\ce{-CH2OH}$ has $\ce{-O}$.However , acc to CIP rule i only need to chech the mass number and not the double bond until i need to break a tie.so both compounds are attached to $\ce{O}$.

then $\ce{-CHO}$ is attached to nothing while $\ce{-CH2OH}$ is attached to $\ce{H}$,hence as they are of dissimilar lengths $\ce{-CH2OH}$ should have the higher priority.
what is wrong with my approach

Comment: You can't ignore the double bond.

Comment: @IvanNeretin But isn't the double bond used only in case of Ties.that is when all the atoms in both chains have same atomic number?

Comment: [Here](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/StudyAids.html#Stereochemistry) is a resource.  Look at the 2013 rulles for an introduction. In your case, (O,O,H) > (O,H,H).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karan: Structure **1** not only has the issue that you have addressed, the priority of -CHO vs. -$\ce{CH2OH}$, but also deals with double bond geometry and the configuration at $\ce{C2}$. The Cahn-Ingold-Prelog (CIP) system handles multiple bonds by creating duplicate atoms shown in red in structure **2.** For the C=C bond, $\ce{C3}$ is attached to duplicate atom $\ce{C4}$ while $\ce{C4}$ is attached to duplicate atom $\ce{C3}$. The same logic is applied to the C=O bond. *All duplicate atoms have the same atomic number (at. no.) as their non-duplicate (original) atoms and each one is bonded to three atoms of at. no. zero.* All atoms, even oxygen, are treated as though they were tetravalent.

The digraph is a two-dimensional (circle) representation of the three-dimensional (sphere) aldehyde **1** as one proceeds outward from $\ce{C2}$ to determine the priorities of the surrounding groups. The spheres are numbered in green. In sphere 2 hydrogen has the lowest priority and $\ce{C1}$, $\ce{C3}$ and $\ce{C6}$ are tied. Proceeding to sphere 3, we have $\ce{C1}${O,O,H}, $\ce{C3}${4,4,H} and $\ce{C6}${O,H,H}. Within the braces the atoms are arranged in descending order of at. no. and a one-to-one comparison is made. Clearly, the order of priorities is $\ce{C1}$>$\ce{C6}$>$\ce{C3}$>H.

Just as $\ce{C6}$ is in front of the five-carbon chain, the hydrogen at $\ce{C2}$ is behind the chain. To assign a configuration, point the thumb of your right hand down the $\ce{C2}$-H bond. Now your fingers will point in from $\ce{C1}$ to $\ce{C6}$ to $\ce{C3}$. Accordingly, the configuration at $\ce{C2}$ is "R" (Rectus).

At $\ce{C3}$ and $\ce{C4}$, C>H. The "E" (Entgegen) configuration applies.

[image]